# C++, a number of classes derive from a class, all the derived classes use a class derived from something else but their base uses that clase's base

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm sorry the title is so nasty, it's very hard to explain

```
class BaseState {
protected:
    BaseState();
public:
    void Some();
    void Useful();
    void Methods();
};

class UsefulState: public BaseState {
public:
    void moreUsefulStuff();
};

class SomeUsefulBase {
protected:
    SomeUsefulBase(BaseState* pState) { state = pState; }
    void UsefulMethods() { state->Some(); }
    void Andthings() { state->Useful(); }
public:
    virtual void doSomething() = 0;
protected:
    BaseState* state;
};

class SomethingUseful: public SomeUsefulBase {
public:
    SomethingUseful(UsefulState* pState): SomeUsefulBase(pState) {
        usefulState = pState;
    }
    virtual void doSomething() { usefulState->moreUsefulStuff();} 
protected:
    UsefulState* usefulState;
};
```

then:

```
SomethingUseful whatever(new UsefulState());
```

It's not important where things are allocated but there will be a lot of classes derived from `SomethingUseful` that will use a `UsefulState` however, all the member functions of `SomeUsefulBase` will use the state, but as a `BaseState`

I am hoping there is a better way than using two members (`UsefulState` and `BaseState` pointers in the definitions), I've thought of a union and a template, but that would be ugly.

I also don't want to litter my code with casts, I'm wondering if there is a nicer notation.

There will be one `UsefulState` per operation, and a large tree structure will be formed of various subclasses of `SomethingUseful` and/or subclasses of `SomethingUsefulBase` where a `UsefulState` pointer is expected.

Addendum:
Not sure what's up with SO's syntax highlighting! It seems to be using case to decide if it wants to colour things blue or not.... not sure how that works.

Addendum 2:
In the use this example is derived from there is one state per operation but many things derived from `SomeUsefulBase`, the derived classes will create each other to form a large tree structure (god I sound noobish) but will all require the use of the derived state.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like the standard "abstract factory"-type situation:

```
struct AbstractGadget { virtual ~AbstractGadget() {} };
struct AbstractWidget { virtual ~AbstractWidget() {} };
struct AbstractThingy { virtual ~AbstractThingy() {} };

struct AbstractFactory
{
    virtual ~AbstractFactory() {}

    virtual std::unique_ptr<AbstractGadget> make_gadget() = 0;
    virtual std::unique_ptr<AbstractGadget> make_widget() = 0;
    virtual std::unique_ptr<AbstractGadget> make_thingy() = 0;
};
```

Usage:

```
struct Gadget1 : AbstractGadget { /* ... */ };
struct Widget1 : AbstractWidget { /* ... */ };
struct Thingy1 : AbstractThingy { /* ... */ };

struct Factory1 : AbstractFactory
{
    virtual std::unique_ptr<AbstractGadget> make_gadget()
    {
        return { new Gadget1; }
    }

    // ...
};
```

And so forth for `Factory2` and `Widget3` etc. There's plenty of potential for eliminating boilerplate code with templates here, too.

Consumers might be given an `AbstractFactory & f` and call `f.make_gadget()` etc. to create objects of a suitable type.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, please see the second addendum, also why do you think it got a down-vote? The nasty title?

Comment: @AlecTeal: It's possible to have a large hierarchy of classes which talk about each other mostly via base classes. There's support for covariant-return-type overrides, but you can't have overrides with different *argument* types (contravariant arguments could be defined, but are generally quite useless). Downvote perhaps because of sloppy presentation, lack of spelling and general structure and effort?

Comment: who's Syam, also is that better? I'm fairly new to posting questions, but I am trying I promise! (for some reason @ Ker and tab isn't working, this message should start with @ KerrekSB)

Comment: @AlecTeal Concerning the downvote, it wasn't mine but I for one had a really hard time understanding your question. This seems like a good enough reason to downvote it. As to why Kerrek answered to me, it's because I pointed a small insignificant error in his post and then I deleted my now-useless comment once he fixed it. This often happens on SO... ;)

Comment: Oh I see! Sorry a lot of this is still new to me, yesterday I was on 40 rep, I had a good answer and it got a lot of votes, I'm still very much a noob despite my *looks smug* 299 (GRR! It was 301!) rep now. Thanks for replying @Syam

Comment: @AlecTeal Just a little hint: don't focus too much on reputation, it comes and goes. If you focus on writing good questions/answers, it will increase by itself without you even noticing it. :)

Comment: @syam I feel foolish now, my self esteem was somehow tied to that downvote XD

Comment: @AlecTeal Wait for your first wave of mass-downvotes because somehow people didn't like your post, then you'll have to forcibly untie your self-esteem from your rep unless you go mad. ;) Keep in mind that votes don't reflect "*what **you** are worth*" but "*what others think of **one** particular message*". (also, we should probably stop the discussion here, comments are not meant for chatting, they're only for improving both questions and answers)

Comment: @syam I've just had 3 questions downvoted, I made an enemy on a chat yesterday, some character called HamZa, he started commenting on my answers and such, should I just "not care" some of the questions are 3 months old, one answered a question I had to learn Postscript myself to answer (I say learn, I'm not fluent), rep doesn't matter at all, you're sure? I am not alleging it is is this guy, but does the "malicious downvote" exist? should someone hate me?

Comment: @Alec [What you are describing is serial downvoting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me). If you are *actually* a victim of this (ie. if it's not just a coincidence) then you don't need to do anything, the system will catch it in time and reverse it (as explained in the linked Meta post). Again, don't worry too much about your rep here: after all it's just a bunch of bytes on the internet, nothing life threatening. ;) And in any case the developers of SO have put more safeguards in place than you could think about...

Comment: I know I ought not do this @syam but I need some way to convey a thank you to you, thank you for that link and the general help. I'd private message you if I could! Thanks ever so much. Now I've stated the compulsion to show gratitude where it is deserved, and shown gratitude, I will stop commenting. Sorry for the inbox spam Kerrek SB.